# Error mapping types ... Map configuration ... Destination Member

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map to instance using Automapper in C#. This is my Automapper configuration

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Model.AutoGenerated.Daily.Entity, Model.AutoGenerated.Monthly.Entity.Entity>();
    }
}
```

and in my services,

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model.AutoGenerated.Daily.PFA));

using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)))
{
    var pfaCollection = (Model.AutoGenerated.Daily.PFA)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    foreach (var entity in pfaCollection.Records.Entity)
    {
        **var commonEntity = _mapper.Map<Model.AutoGenerated.Monthly.Entity.Entity>(entity);** 
    }
}
```

But it breaks at the last line `_mapper.Map` with error message

> "Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nEntity ->
> Entity\r\nxxx.Model.AutoGenerated.Daily.Entity ->
> xxx.Model.AutoGenerated.Monthly.Entity.Entity\r\n\r\nType
> Map configuration:\r\nEntity ->
> Entity\r\nxxx.Model.AutoGenerated.Daily.Entity ->
> xxx.Model.AutoGenerated.Monthly.Entity.Entity\r\n\r\nDestination
> Member:\r\nNameDetails\r\n"

I search for `NameDetails` and compared both classes and they looked the same. On the left is Monthly.Entity.Entity and one the right is Daily.Entity

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your screenshot shows, the properties `NameDetails` themselves are of class type `NameDetails` and `AutoMapper` needs a map defined between those classes.

In your `MappingProfile`, add a map like -

```
CreateMap<Model.AutoGenerated.Daily.NameDetails, Model.AutoGenerated.Monthly.Entity.NameDetails>();
```

I assumed the namespaces based on your map for `Entity`, but they might differ.

Also, you'll need similar maps defined for other class types like `Descriptions` etc.